# SonarJS code coverage is shown as 0

Tags: sonarqube, lcov, sonarjs

I am using SonarQube 6.5, And trying import lcov.info file for code coverage using sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths property.

My build is done using Jenkins. code is deployed and tested at /path/to/Deploydirectory/parent-project1/project1/ and reports are generated in jenkins workspace  /path/to/jenkins/workspace/BUILD_DEPLOY/parent-project1/project1/coverage.

I am using istanbul for code coverage as

```
"scripts": {
"coverage": "./node_modules/.bin/istanbul  cover 
             node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha --dir=/path/to/jenkins/workspace/BUILD_DEPLOY/parent-project1/project1/coverage"
```

},

lcov.info are generated as below

```
         TN:
         SF:/path/to/Deploydirectory/project1/package/plugins/file1.js
         FN:11,convetUTCtoLocal
         FN:17,customCallback
         FN:26,(anonymous_3)
         FN:50,(anonymous_4)
         FN:68,(anonymous_5)
         FN:95,(anonymous_6)
         ......
```

On SonarQube getting error

> Could not resolve 2 file paths in  [/path/to/jenkins/workspace/BUILD_DEPLOY/parent-project1/project1/coverage/lcov.info,
>    /path/to/jenkins/workspace/BUILD_DEPLOY/parent-project2/project2/coverage/lcov.info],
>   first unresolved path:
>   /path/to/Deploydirectory/parent-project1/project1/file1.js

sonrQube config

```
sonar.inclusions=**/*.js
sonar.scm.disabled=true
sonar.sources=$WORKSPACE
sonar.java.binaries=$WORKSPACE
sonar.projectBaseDir=/path/to

sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=
/path/to/jenkins/workspace/BUILD_DEPLOY/parent-
project1/project1/coverage/lcov.info, 
/path/to/jenkins/workspace/BUILD_DEPLOY/parent- 
project2/project2/coverage/lcov.info

sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have some property in your `sonar-project.properties` that's conflicting with reporting, possibly a pathing issue?

Having generated the `lcov.info` file, and telling sonar-scanner where it is via `sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths` ([a comma-separated list](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JavaScript+Coverage+Results+Import)) will upload your coverage correctly.

Considering the case where coverage is generated with `nyc` NPM module (or `istanbul` in your case, as long as the lcov file is generated), the coverage script and the sonar config would be the following:

`package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "coverage": "nyc npm test",
    "test": "mocha tests/unit/*.js"
  },
```

`sonar-project.properties`:

```
sonar.host.url=https://sonarqube.server
sonar.scm.disabled=true

sonar.projectKey=my-app
sonar.projectName=My App
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.language=js

sonar.sources=src

sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
sonar.eslint.reportPaths=eslint-report.json
```